# Error: Could not find or load main class Main Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've recently installed Scala as a part of my functional programming course and I've encountered a problem: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1 (Java version 9, build 9+181) doesn't run any of my scala code, exitting with

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main

This code is an example.

```
object Main {
  def length[A](list:List[A]):Int = {
    if (list == Nil) 0
    else 1 + length(list.tail)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    length(List[Int](1, 4, 5, 12, -1))
  }
}
```

It's really simple, yet IntelliJ refuses to run it. Windows CMD doesn't even react to a scala command, resulting into

> 'scala' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

even though I have it installed on my computer. If I call Scala Console inside of IntelliJ everything works fine and compiles as expected. I've tried switching to JDK 1.8 inside of IntelliJ, yet it led to no result.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have the scala plugin installed in IntelliJ? As for not being able to run the scala command, that sounds like the scala compiler has not been set in your PATH variable

Comment: Yes, I definitely have the intellij plugin installed. Could you specify, what you mean by 'the scala compiler has not been set in your PATH variable'?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable) - essentially, it's a list of locations that your operating system looks into for programs to run. When you type 'scala' in CMD, it looks to see if scala is in any of those locations. So you need to find the location you installed scala to, and add it to that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it turns out that the `src/main` was not marked as `Sources Root`[image]
which causes the following error

```
...
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So of course after I mark the `src/main` as `Sources Root`, the Scala Hello World example runs happy again.

**Notice the blue color of directory `src/main` when it's marked as `Sources Root`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the little green arrow to run the program from inside of your Main object?

How did you create the program? It could be that your `build` file SBT configuration of the project is a different Scala version than what's installed on your computer.

> It's really simple, yet IntelliJ refuses to run it. Windows CMD
>   doesn't even react to a scala command, resulting into
>
> ```
> 'scala' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> ```

This means that Scala is not added to your class path in your terminal. Look up how to do that and see if that doesn't help out your IntelliJ problem too.